# Dart - The return type 'bool Function()' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context

Tags: dart

So I have the following piece of code:

```
extension on String {
  bool isSpace() {
    return trim().isEmpty;
  }
}

List<String> getWords(String input) {
  List<String> result = input.split(" ");
  result.removeWhere((word) => word.isSpace);
  return result;
}
```

When I run it, I get [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmZ3Q.png): "The return type 'bool Function()' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context."

I tried checking and reading the documentation but I still don't get what exactly is wrong...does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`word.isSpace` is a function.  `word.isSpace()` is the invocation of that function.  I think you want the latter.  Or change your extension to be a getter instead of a method.

Comment: Well that was a silly error on my side. Yes, a getter is what I wanted to end up doing, thanks for your help!